# java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

приложение для чтения новостей на котлине. используется newsapi.org ошибка
01-17 13:54:52.917 17272-17272/com.rediolashabanaj.kotlinnews E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.rediolashabanaj.kotlinnews, PID: 17272
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Изображение на экране невозможно воспроизвести. Надо указывать текст ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

В строке 11 видите значок? Это рекурсия. Насколько я понял, метод `get()` создает новый класс, вызывает у него метод `get()`, который создает новый класс и вызывает у него `get()` и так далее.